# Can't burn ISO to CD

Tags: iso

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS which was installed with WUBI.

My Windows became corrupt, so I need a installation CD to repair it. I downloaded the ISO image and took 'Open with Brasero' (I also tried 'Write to Disk'). The Burning Process get completed (That's what I think) and the window shows 100% Completed. But a process is still going on saying 'creating image checksum'. It shows no progress although the window is not frozen.

Either please instruct a way to fix this or recommend a good software that burns ISO image to CD without fail. Or you could tell me if there is a software for burning it into a USB Flash Drive WITHOUT needing to format it.

Comment: It sounds like bad media (CD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use k3b, which is very powerful and easy to use burner. Also you can make your usb flash drive as a installation media. But for that you  need to format(not manually, apps will) your flash drive. UnetBootin is a application(in ubuntu repositories) by which you can use your flash drive as a bootable device.